# Android apps losing files

Tags: android, file

I'm looking for someone who might be able to suggest ANYTHING that might explain this problem I've been having.  I've been having this problem for almost three years, with the same app, and nothing I have tried fixes it, or even explains what's going on.  The app is a little game, and it saves its state in three files inside one level of folder, like so:

```
USERNAME
    gamestate1.dat
    gameinfo.dat
    gamestuff.cfg
```

So what happens is, people will play the game, then suddenly the next day they'll play it again and data will be wiped.  Sometimes all files (and the folder) are gone.  Sometimes one or two files are missing.  It's not common,but it's happening enough that it's occupying too much support time.

The game itself has nothing in it that deletes files at all.  The game doesn't delete.  But the files are vanishing somehow anyway.  The game is not a hardcore game for hardcore players, so most of my users are tech-ignorant, so I know they're not going in an deleting the files.

The rate of customers complaining that they've lost everything increases exponentially right after I push an update.

Can anyone tell me if there's ANY kind of special situation on android that could cause this, and how I could prevent it?  Is some antivirus on some phones?  Could it be sectors on the card going bad?  I've tried turning Google sync on and off and every which way, and turning sync off seems to reduce the problem without eliminating it.

I'm using JNI and accessing my files with normal C++ file functions-- fopen, fwrite, fread, fclose.  I am saving them in the folder returned via getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath().

Comment: Are you saving it to the cache directory?  Those files are periodically deleted by the OS.

Comment: No saving to getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();  Functionally, it ends up Android/Data/com.company.app/